# Delete and Replace within Case statements

Tags: sql

I am having to do a lot of data validations on several worksheets. One of the common problems I face is shown below. I have 4 columns with a row number over the group.

Example 1

I would like to remove row 2 and 4 as the Visit '1st' takes precedence.

Example 2

I would like to keep row one as is but change rows 2 3 4 to '2nd'. Can anyone suggest a quick and clean way to do this. I have tried using case and replace (using some of the examples on the site) but I am not too happy with the results.

Thanks in Advance

Example 1

```
Row     ID     Date           Visit
 1       A     2014-04-10     1st
 2       A     2014-04-10     2nd
 3       A     2014-04-17     1st
 4       A     2014-04-17     2nd
```

Example 2

```
Row     ID     Date           Visit
 1       A     2014-04-10     1st
 2       A     2014-04-10     1st
 3       A     2014-04-17     1st
 4       A     2014-04-17     1st
```

Comment: Is this Excel or Access or something else?

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: My question is what is the best sql statement to handle these 2 types of issues. (I have thousands of records in my table!)

Comment: use an int for Visit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first example:

```
DELETE t FROM [table] t WHERE t.[Visit] = '2nd'
```

and the second

```
UPDATE t
   SET [Visit] = CASE [Row] WHEN 1 THEN '1st'
                            ELSE '2nd'
                 END
  FROM [table] t
```

Or, when you say "row number" are you actually using the ROW_NUMBER function in SQL?

Comment: @Kello - in your problem statement for Example 1, you indicate you want to KEEP row 3 but your comment on Bobcat's solution infers a DELETE statement which would remove Row 3 and keep rows 2 and 4.

Comment: Thanks for your response. It was update that I wanted all along. I tinkered about with your statement and eventually got what I wanted. It isn't perfect but it will do!

Answer (score 0):

You are best using the "If" function for this problem.

For example:

```
   If (select COUNT(*) from table where criteria) > 1
    drop delete from
    where criteria
```

Comment: Select* from MyTable                                           Delete from MyTable                                             Where Visit = '1st' and Row > 1                                      This is one of the statements I have tried for Example1. Can anyone improve on this to get the desired result?